# Add eventListener in IE javascript

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, events, listener

This code works nicely in for example Chrome, but not in Internet Explorer 8/9.

```
/* sitepoint.com/javascript-this-event-handlers */
function AttachEvent(element, type, handler){if (element.addEventListener){element.addEventListener(type, handler, false);}else{element.attachEvent("on"+type, handler);}}

window.addEventListener("load", function() {

            //do some stuff

            AttachEvent(id, "click", function_name); 

}, false);
```

IE already complains about the addEventListener line.
I believe I need to use attachEvent instead. How do I do this? I would prefer to keep the code that is working in the other browsers and only use attachEvent in Internet Explorer.
How do I get this cross-browser compatible?

Comment: This is where JS libraries such as jQuery shine.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

IE9 *does* support `addEventListener()`.

Here is how your existing function would work with `attachEvent` (and the old `on*` property).

```
// logic to attach the event correctly in IE9
function AttachEvent(element, type, handler) {
    if (element.addEventListener) {
        element.addEventListener(type, handler, false);
    }else if (element.attachEvent) {
        element.attachEvent('on' + type, handler)
    } else {
        element['on' + type] = handler;
    }
}
```

You'd then set the window load event...

```
AttachEvent(window, "load", function() {
    // ...
});
```

Don't forget that the `event` is global with the older IEs. You could script around that if you wanted to. You'd simply have each function call this `callback()` which would go on to invoke the user-supplied `handler()` with the correct arguments.

```
var callback = function(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    handler.call(element, e);
};
```

You could get carried away and try and normalise properties on `event`, such as `target`/`srcElement`, but then you might want to consider an existing library.

Comment: Ah, okay, yes. I can just reused that function, good idea. I will try it out.